# Unable to login my magento 1.9 web admin panel

Tags: cpanel, magento-1.9

I've recently installed `Magento 1.9.4.3` on my `cPanel`. Setup was successful without any error but now I'm unable to login to the admin panel.

Please guide me what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install a clean version by installer or an upgrade to an existing version?

On new installations it could be an Cookie issue (base un/secure URL) not set as well as cookie domain in database, which causes the admin panel to just reload.

If you updated an existing version, try to delete your cookies and cache. Sometimes, after installing (or changing, session save type, module installation etc) the admin panel is just reloading. Deleting the cookies and forcing a reload on the page, fixes it most times. If not, just send a message for more instructions

Comment: I've tried these things but the issue isn't resolved... please help me resolve it; have a fresh installation

Comment: Do you have access to the database? any sample data installed? Did you use the magento installer or something else?

Comment: I've installed through Cpanel web application and for your info just tell you that after inputting admin ID & Password and clicking on the login button it's showing a blank/white page i mean without any info/data... Please help me to resolve it

Comment: Hmm thats kinda difficult, cause usually the the installation process is triggered if you install a clean magento version. Where did you install it? Which cPanel system?